# Can I broadcast small data between ESP8266s without a need to connect to any network?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to send small (a few bytes) data from one ESP8266 to another over long distances.

I believe the signal is too weak to connect one ESP8266 to another but maybe they can receive small messages with some delay?

How can I achieve that using arduino-esp8266 library (or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

If ESP8266 boards can not connect directly to each other because of the weak signal (approximately more than 50m between them) you can still connect them to each other (indirectly) if they are connected to the same WiFi network created by external router or internet. But you can connect them to each other without need to connect to any external network only if they are in range of each other.

It both of them are connected to same local WiFi network router you can communicate between them as if they are connected directly to each other. Just in this case router option "WiFi Client isolation" must be disabled in router settings page for boards to see each other(in case that router has this or similar named option).

Otherwise if ESP boards are connected to totally different networks, but both of these networks have access to internet, you can still connect them to each other but then you must use port forwarding on each router, so both of the ESP8266 boards are visible form internet. Google a bit about it, it is not so complicated. In this case you can have boards on any two locations in the world and make them communicate to each other as long as they are accessible from internet.

Maybe it is hard to test it when your code do not work out of the box, so I would recommend that you use some TCP or UDP terminal to test connectivity between two WiFi clients on different or same network. There are buch of such terminals available online.

For example for sending and receiving UDP packets same way as you would send/receive data from serial port, I use Docklight Scripting.
https://docklight.de/downloads/
I actually use it also for other Serial port communication so no big difference there. Don't let description text on their page fool you. It  can also send/receive TCP/UDP data  :)

Just when you create new project go to tools->project settings and type IP and port of another device you want to connect with (this can be another PC running docklight scripting or your ESP board). For example in my case I type in 
Send/Receive Comm.:  UDP:192.168.0.154:9761
Because that is the IP of my ESP board on local WiFi network and press "play button"or F5. Now you can send receive data to your board using UDP in same way that you communicate to basic serial port and in such way test basic connectivity. Or even use two laptops just to confirm connectivity between two WiFi clients on network.

And third hardest option must most versatile is needed if you do not have access to routers setup page (they are password protected) and cannot set port forwarding, then you must create server application on some server that is visible from internet and has public IP. So both of your ESP8266 boards are connected to this server as clients (for client port forwarding do not need to be set but in this case you must have access to internet by both clients) and server can forward their messages to each other. But this is way out of this topics scope. Maybe for start you use TCP/UDP terminal just to check connectivity between two WiFi clients and see if ESP8266 can communicate directly or not. Docklight scripting is just suggestion because it is my personal choice for TCP/UDP/RS232/RS485/MODBUS/USB HID, but you can use other software for this.

I hope this helps a bit about ways to connect two ESP8266 boards indirectly.

Comment: I'm asking specifically about sending information from one ESP to another directly. I know that they won't connect in a sense of connecting one ESP with station mode to another with AP mode - I think there's another way to this - perhaps send information in SSIDs? However, thanks anyway.